# Choosing “with” vs. “in”

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

While doing some formal writing at my office,  my friend told me that *in* is more apt than *with* in the following sentence. However, my understanding says when we talk about tools of action, we generally use *with*.

> A gazetted officer is required to sign **with/in** green ink.

So which is more apt here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sign **in** green ink* is grammatically and semantically correct and also idiomatic.

Use *with* in reference to the pen, not the ink -- the pen is the 'tool' you refer to, while the ink is a medium at most. As in *sign with a green pen*.

Comment: I might want to add that the question has quite a few simple and avoidable errors in it. Follow our sister site ELL Q&A http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: The medium/style requirement for 'in' is obvious with 'write in French' and 'write in a florid style'. Ink is not an abstract noun, however: the choice of preposition could probably have gone either way historically. Indeed, 'they paint P oils' may use either preposition.

Answer (score 1):

I think using 'in' is better in this situation due to the signing IN pen. But with is also acceptable, in the context of 'signing in with/using a green pen'.

Comment: So both are correct here?

Comment: @Sudhir yes, *with* is allowed because *with* generally applies to something used to perform an action, but *in* is allowed because the signature would be *in* that ink, and as both answers have said, that would be the more usual.